# Missing link to static library

Tags: go, settings, environment

Running a `go run main.go` I get a strange error message:

```
danilo@lm ~/godev/src/quick $ go run main.go 
command-line-arguments
/usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: cannot open file /usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/valyala/quicktemplate.a: open /usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/valyala/quicktemplate.a: no such file or directory`
```

Here is my environment:

Linux Mint 18

GOLANG ENV:

```
danilo@lm ~/godev/src/quick $ go env
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/home/danilo/godev/bin"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/danilo/godev"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/lib/go-1.6"
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT="1"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

My $GOPATH tree:

```
.(godev)
├── bin
│   └── qtc
├── pkg
│   └── linux_amd64
│       └── github.com
│           └── valyala
│               ├── bytebufferpool.a
│               └── quicktemplate.a
└── src
    ├── github.com
    │   └── valyala
    │       ├── bytebufferpool
    │       │   ├── ...
    │       └── quicktemplate
    │           ├── ...
    └── quick
        ├── main.go
        └── templates
            ├── hello.qtpl
            └── hello.qtpl.go
```

It seems like to miss the `pkg` folder in my workspace where the static libraries are stored!
Am I right?

Comment: Seems like it's trying to open "/usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/valyala/quicktemplate.a: open /usr/lib/go-1.6/pkg/linux_amd64/github.com/valyala/quicktemplate.a"?

Comment: cmd/compile: "dot import" causes confusing error

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I solved. The `main.go` code was:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "./templates"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", templates.Hello("Foo"))
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", templates.Hello("Bar"))
}
```

so I missed to use absolute path in the import section:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "quick/templates"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", templates.Hello("Foo"))
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", templates.Hello("Bar"))
}
```